# Diferencias entre variables estáticas y parámetros de un constructor

Tags: java, variables, constructor

Estoy programando una interfaz gráfica de un proyecto en java, la cual tiene permisos de acceso y diferente funcionalidad dependiendo del rol de usuario con el que se ingrese

Todo iba bien en el proyecto hasta que llegue a esta interfaz, púes empiezo a tener problemas de como programar los permisos, es decir, que un usuario **técnico** no pueda modificar los campos de texto editables por el usuario **capturista**, y viceversa (hay más problemas parecidos a este porque el programa está conectado a una base de datos)

```
public InfoEquip(boolean observaciones_capturista, boolean comentarios_tecnico) {

        setTitle(GestEquip.Titulo + InfoClien.Titulo);    // Sumo dos Strings, pero en esta suma una de estas variables siempre estara vacia.
        TextArea_Observaciones.setEditable(observaciones_capturista);    // Recibo el primer parametro, cambio la edicion de un JTextArea
        TextArea_Comrentarios.setEditable(comentarios_tecnico);  // De igual manera
```

Se puede ver como utilizo las variable estatica para poner el titulo a la interfaz, ya que esta puede ser llamada desde dos clases diferentes y dependiendo de esto el titulo debe cambiar; y paramatros para cambiar la edicion de dos JTextArea que hay en ella, dependiendo del rol de usuario. Aun asi, creo que ambas cosas las puedo hacer, igual con los parametros y con las variables estaticas...

El problema logro resolverlo, sólo que, al ser principiante, no se que manera se vería mejor en cuanto al código, si pasándole parametros al constructor de esta clase o simplemente usando variables estáticas de otras clases como **Login**, que es donde se guarda el rol de usuario.

La cuestión en sí, es en que momentos específicos se utiliza un parametro para el constructor y en que momento se utiliza la variable estática, ya que las estoy utilizando casi que de igual manera.
Aparte, siento que si le añado más de 3 parámetros al constructor ya se ve mal...

Pdta: No estaba seguro de hacer esta pregunta, pues es un poco confusa... Agradezco las posibles respuestas

Comment: Juan, publica un codigo de ejemplo para poder ayudarte. De lo contrario no creo que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo de cuando pasar un valor al constructor y cuando usar constantes de otras clases, depende mucho de lo que estés haciendo, aunque teniendo en cuenta la filosofía de Java de compartimentar el código, te puedo dar algunas recomendaciones:

- Cuanto menos necesite saber una clase de otra, más desacoplado estará tu código y en el momento que necesites modificar algo, toda la información relevante a ese problema se encontrará en el mismo lugar.
- Java permite sobrecarga de constructores, siempre puedes tener dos o más constructores que reciban diferentes parámetros, aprovecha esto para definir "parámetros fijos" que casi nunca vayas a usar.
- Si usas muchos parámetros a menudo, utiliza una clase como Wrapper:

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject("Hola", 3, 4, "Admin"); //Demasiados parámetros?
MyObject mo = new MyObject(config);

Class config{
    private String saludo;
    private int id;
    private int loQueSea;
    private String Rol;
}
```

Usando clases como wrappers en muchas ocasiones puedes agrupar parámetros que tienen un propósito similar.